# How to get user edited value of a JFormattedTextField that is updated 3 times/sec by a Swing Timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jformattedtextfield, focuslistener

I have a `JFormattedTextField` component with an `Integer` value that is updated 3 times in a second when it doesn't have focus.

For updating the value I use Swing Timer.

I want to make it possible for user to edit its value(to update some value in the model) but I know that the value of a `JFormattedTextField` isn't updated every time it loses the focus. so it's not  wise to change the model attributes in the lostFocus event and on the other hand when it loses the focus its value can be changed by the updater module which makes the situation more difficult.

It is clear that I can't use the `propertyListener` neither, because the value is updated 3 times in a second!

Now I wonder how I will be able to update the variable on place profiting `JFormattedTextField` capabilities and let updater update my JFormattedTextField when it doesn't have focus! Is it possible or I must use an `inputDialog` instead? How?

For example in the following code when I change the field value to 200 in the GUI and then click on the JFrame to make it lose focus the value printed in the console isn't 200. It's a great random value that was previously in the field.

```
public class SwingTimerFormattedTextFieldTester {

    public static void main(String... args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
        final JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(new Long(100));
        field.setColumns(20);
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.requestFocus();
                e.consume();
            }


        });

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(field);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(330, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!field.hasFocus()){
                    field.setValue(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong());
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                field.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                System.out.println(String.valueOf((Long)field.getValue()));
            }
        });

        frame.requestFocus();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't get an answer soon, then it would be best to show an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Good comment. Maybe I should have added it from the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you commit the edit to the JFormattedTextField on focus lost?

```
 @Override
 public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    try {
       if (field.isEditValid()) {
          field.commitEdit();
       }
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf((Long) field.getValue()));
 }
```

Comment: Excellent man! @HovercraftFullOfEels May I ask you how you have become a professional Swing developer? I think It's not permitted to ask it in stackoverflow as a question. But are there some books or resources to master Swing/JavaFX professionally and systematically?

Comment: @puk: I am not a professional Swing developer but a hobbiest. I have learned most through creating projects with Swing, through the tutorials, through the API especially, some through the Swing source code, and much through here. This solution above came from the FormattedTextField API. If you go there, you'll see that it has special considerations for focus lost.